# Why mongo query is showing undefined in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to check the data with `findOne` when im trying with the postman getting undefined in console.log , i checked with the same query in roboMongo and its showing the data

this is the result:-

[image]

Here is the code:-

```
exports.signIn = async( req, res ) => {
    const {
      userEmailPhone,
    } = req.body;

await  User.findOne ({ email : userEmailPhone}).then((err, user)=> {
  console.log("user..", user)
 if (user){
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "sucess"
    });
  }
 })
}
```

the postman response:-

[image]

Comment: Can you add your postman request?

Comment: i added postman response.. actually the response is not showing its lagging

Comment: const {
      email
    } = req.body;
also use email in query

Comment: Also why are you using await and then together

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using async - await, I believe there is no need of using the `.then()`  block.

Your code should be updated to use async and await as below:

```
exports.signIn = async( req, res ) => {
    const { email } = req.body;

const user = await  User.findOne ({ email : userEmailPhone})
  console.log("user..", user)
 if (user){
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "sucess"
    });
  }
}
```

If you still want to use the .then() block, I would recommend making the following changes in the code:

```
exports.signIn = async ( req, res ) => {
    const {email} = req.body;
    User.findOne ({ email : email}).then((user, err)=> {
     console.log("user..", user)
     if (user){
     res.status(200).send({
       message: "sucess"
     });
   }
 })
}
```

Since the promise callback for MongoDb queries has the following callback format:

```
.then( (res, err)  => {
     // do stuff
})
```

Reference : https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/promises/

Answer (score 0):

You are sending raw json data. First you should use `app.use(bodyParser.json());`. Only `app.use(bodyParser());` is deprecated.

This should fix it assuming you have a json body-parser

```
exports.signIn = async( req, res ) => {
    const {email} = req.body;
    User.findOne ({ email : email}).then((err, user)=> {
     console.log("user..", user)
     if (user){
     res.status(200).send({
       message: "sucess"
     });
   }
 })
}
```

Comment: still getting undefined

Comment: do you have body-parser ? console.log(req.body)

Comment: no, body-parser is deprecated 
i added `console.log(req.body)`
this is the result :-
{ email: 'susjj@gmail.com' }
user.. undefined

Comment: You still need *a* body parsing middleware: [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body)

Comment: I have updated my ans @Mohan. Please check now